# Insert multi-dimensional data into tables using only MySQL code

Tags: mysql

I'm exploring the possibility of using mysql procedures to do insert statements of json objects that embed other json objects.  Let's say I created these two mysql tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `course` (
  `course_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `enrollment_date` date NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `courses_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And let's say I'm receiving the following JSON object which I intend to transform and insert into the student and course table:

```
let payload = [
    {
        name:"Alice",
        birth_date:"1968-01-28",
        courses:[
            {course_id:4325,enrollment_date:"2018-05-01"},
            {course_id:3119,enrollment_date:"2018-09-01"},
            {course_id:1302,enrollment_date:"2018-01-01"},
        ],
    },
    {
        name:"Bob",
        birth_date:"1971-10-01",
        courses:[
            {course_id:2000,enrollment_date:"2018-09-01"},
            {course_id:3109,enrollment_date:"2018-09-01"},
            {course_id:4305,enrollment_date:"2018-09-01"},
        ],
    },
];
```

In the past, I would insert the json data using client side code that does something like this

```
foreach (payload as student) {
    studentId = exec_prepared_statement("INSERT INTO student SET name= ?, birth_date = ?",student.name,student.birth_date)
    foreach(student.courses as course){
        courseId = exec_prepared_statement("INSERT INTO course SET student_id = ?, course_id = ?, enrollment_date = ?",studentId, course.course_id,course.enrollment_date)
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to achieve this series of insert behaviour using purely MySQL code because I'm not sure how to pass multi-dimensional data into a mysql stored procedure.  It will be great if I can see an example of that somewhere.

Alternatively, someone can tell me if I should completely avoid trying to insert multi-dimensional data via purely MySQL code...that I should have client-side code like PHP, Go, JS do the job?  I'd really like to see what this would look like with just MySQL so I can compare which one is more maintainable.

Comment: This is difficult to do in SQL, it doesn't have any structured data types like arrays and objects that you can loop over.

Comment: In general you use tables to implement arrays, but this is not much help if the task is filling the tables in the first place.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 adds a JSON datatype, you could use that.

Comment: @Barmar do you know how well the JSON data type is supported in recent versions of other relational databases like PostGres, SQL Server etc..?  My thinking is that if I should change to another relational db technology, does putting all this logic in a MySQL sproc make it easier for migration?  Or having it done in the client side code via a good ORM or data abstraction library does a better job of that

Comment: I don't know anything offhand. I just found Microsoft's documentation on SQL-Server 2016 support by googling, and I'm sure you can do the same for all the other databases you care about. It's probably a new feature in all of them, and I don't know how compatible they all are.

Comment: I would recommend against using JSON datatypes until they are a bit more usable in terms of searching and updating. A properly normalised table is almost always going to be a better solution. Having said that, the only way to loop over arrays in MySQL is with a stored procedure so you may as well do that in your application framework.